# Add Try-Catch Block to XAML Code

Tags: c#, linq, xaml, try-catch

I have the following code and need to add a try-catch-block because e.g. the convert to integer might not work well if the supplied string is wrong. Problem appears only in rare cases, but of course I want o avoid a crash.

```
private async Task<List<MyItem>> ParseFeed(string text)
{
    XNamespace ns = "http://mynamespace/";
    return await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        var xdoc = XDocument.Parse(text);
        return (from XElement item in xdoc.Descendants("item")
                select new MyItem
                {
                    Subject = (string)item.Element(ns + "Subject"),
                    CreationDate = (System.DateTime)System.DateTime.Parse((string)item.Element(ns + "CreationDate")),
                    ItemID = (int)item.Element(ns + "ItemID")
                }).ToList();
    });
}
```

I've tried try-catch in several places but I did not find the correct one :-( Where should I add it? In case the "ItemID" is no Integer I'd like to skip this item and process all the other ones. Would that work?
Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is that you can't use a try/catch in the way you describe.

You have two options:

Firstly, you could abandon LINQ and use a standard `foreach` with `list.Add()` and use try/catch.

The second approach is to extract the `int` conversion out into a separate method that does the try/catch and eg, returns a tuple indicating success and the value, though this can be greatly simplified by using an `Option<int>` type, such as supplied by my own [Succinc<T> library](https://github.com/DavidArno/SuccincT). It supports supplying either a value or none:

```
private async Task<List<MyItem>> ParseFeed(string text)
{
    XNamespace ns = "http://mynamespace/";
    return await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        var xdoc = XDocument.Parse(text);
        return (from XElement item in xdoc.Descendants("item")
                let possibleItemID = item.Element(ns + "ItemID").ParseInt()
                where possibleItemID.HasValue
                select new MyItem
                {
                    Subject = (string)item.Element(ns + "Subject"),
                    CreationDate = (System.DateTime)System.DateTime.Parse((string)item.Element(ns + "CreationDate")),
                    ItemID = possibleItemID.Value
                }).ToList();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're just worried about `ItemID` not being an integer, then add a `where` clause:

```
int itemId;
return (from XElement item in xdoc.Descendants("item")
        where int.TryParse(item.Element(ns + "ItemID"), out itemId)
        select new MyItem
        {
            Subject = (string)item.Element(ns + "Subject"),
            CreationDate = (System.DateTime)System.DateTime.Parse((string)item.Element(ns + "CreationDate")),
            ItemID = itemId
        }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a static method that can convert string/object/T to Int32 and handles any of the exceptions thrown during conversion. Be noted that you cannot use these kind of methods for LINQ to Entities/Xml, rather you will need to call on .ToList() after first select and this will be you raw data than .select(... that raw data that will use the desired conversion method. Here is the code sample.

```
private async Task<List<MyItem>> ParseFeed(string text)
{


    XNamespace ns = "http://mynamespace/";
    return await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        var xdoc = XDocument.Parse(text);
        return (from XElement item in xdoc.Descendants("item")
                select new
                {
                    Subject = (string)item.Element(ns + "Subject"),
                    CreationDate =    (System.DateTime)System.DateTime.Parse((string)item.Element(ns + "CreationDate")),
                    ItemID = ns 
                }).ToList()
                    .select(x=> new MyItem{
                        x.Subject,
                        x.CreationDate, 
                        ItemID  = SafeConvert.ToInt32(ns)
                    }).ToList();
    });
}
```

You can bundle Conversion methods with exception handeling like following

```
public static class SafeConvert
{
    public static int ToInt32(object number)
    {
        try
        {
            // if (TypeValidator.IsInt(number)) // If you want to check type before cast to avoid any potential exceptions
            return Convert.ToInt32(number);
        }
        catch
        { // Log you exception}
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally I'd just switch from Linq to a regular `foreach` loop and use the `TryParse` methods

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Parse(text);
var list = new List<MyItem>();
foreach(var item in xdoc.Descendants("item"))
{
    DateTime creationDate;
    int itemId;
    if(int.TryParse((string)item.Element(ns + "ItemID"),out itemId)
       && DateTime.TryParse((string)item.Element(ns + "CreationDate"), out creationDate))
    {
        list.Add(new MyItem
            {
                Subject = (string)item.Element(ns + "Subject"),
                CreationDate = creationDate,
                ItemID = itemId
            });
    }
}

return list;
```